# Is there a way to populate a UserForm Listbox with Values from Scripting Dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to populate two different list boxes with the same scripting dictionary but it isn't working.

I've got two subs that i'm running, one calls on the other.

Here is the original Sub (working code):

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub NewWire()

Call PopulateClientName
NewWireForm.Show

End Sub

Sub PopulateClientName()
Dim FileName As String
Dim twb As Workbook, awb As Workbook
Dim aws As Worksheet, tws As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim rg1 As Range, rg2 As Variant
Dim rCell As Range

'//Clear combobox
DirectCalls.ClientName.Clear
ThirdParty.ClientName.Clear
Transfers.ClientName.Clear


'Open Master Client List
Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New")
tws.Visible = True

FileName = "C:\Users\nleon\Documents\Client Master List.xlsx"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open FileName
Set awb = ActiveWorkbook
Set aws = awb.Worksheets("Client Info")
Set ws = awb.Worksheets("Fund Info")
Set rg1 = aws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set rg2 = ws.Range("A2").CurrentRegion

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each rCell In aws.Range("B2", aws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        If Not .exists(rCell.Value) Then
            .Add rCell.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next rCell

 DirectCalls.ClientName.List = .Keys
 ThirdParty.ClientName.List = .Keys
 Transfers.ClientName.List = .Keys
 
End With

Call PopulateClientNo(rg1, aws)
Call PopulateFund(rg2, ws)

awb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub

Sub PopulateClientNo(rg1 As Range, aws As Worksheet)
Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Dim rCell As Range

'//Clear combobox
DirectCalls.ClientNo.Clear
ThirdParty.ClientNo.Clear
Transfers.ClientNo.Clear


With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each rCell In aws.Range("C2", aws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        If Not .exists(rCell.Value) Then
            .Add rCell.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next rCell

 DirectCalls.ClientNo.List = .Keys
 ThirdParty.ClientNo.List = .Keys
 Transfers.ClientNo.List = .Keys

End With

End Sub
```

here's the sub isn't working:

```
Sub PopulateFund(rg2 As Variant, ws As Worksheet)
Dim dict As Object, d As Variant
Dim result As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, v As Variant

CapitalCalls.DCMFund.Clear
CapitalCalls.FundDesc.Clear

d = rg2.Value2
If Not IsArray(d) Then d = Array(d)
Debug.Print IsArray(d)

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To UBound(d, 1)
    For j = 2 To 2
        If dict.exists(d(i, j)) = False Then
            dict.Add Key:=d(i, j), Item:=d(i, j + 1)
        Else
            result = result + d(i, j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

CapitalCalls.DCMFund.List = dict.Keys -----> this isn't actually working
CapitalCalls.FundDesc.List = dict.Item -----> this isn't actually working


End Sub
```

---

Within the Userform called "NewWireForm" exists the following code:

```
Option Base 1

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
Unload Me
End
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Frame1
        With .Font
            .Bold = False
            .Name = "Ariel"
            .Size = 14
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub NextButton_Click()

If TPExpense = True Then
 ThirdParty.Show

ElseIf DCMCC = True Then
 CapitalCalls.Show
 
ElseIf DirectCC = True Then
 DirectCalls.Show

ElseIf Transfer = True Then
 Transfers.Show
 
Else: MsgBox ("You have not selected a wire type. Please try again!.")
End If

End Sub
```

I am expecting the lists within the "capital call" userform to populate with the keys and items from the dictionary but it comes up blank.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What is that `On Error Resume Next` for?

Comment: ...if you remove it what happens when you run your code?

Comment: You should add the items in the same loop; the ListBox has an **.AddItem** method that has to be invoked before adding another item; like (.AddItem: .List(.ListCount-1) = "texthere").

Comment: @TimWilliams there is no error, i can see, through the locals window, that the items are being added to the dictionary. Its filling the list that is causing the issue.

Comment: Surprised that `dict.Item` doesn't cause a problem - I think you might want `dict.Items` there.  If you `Debug.Print dict.Count` d o you get what you expect?

Comment: @TimWilliams - I updated to Items and still the listbox is blank. Per the immediate window, i am seeing the correct count.

Comment: It's working fine for me.  Is `CapitalCalls` a worksheet or a userform?

Comment: @TimWilliams it is a userform

Comment: And is that code running in the userform, or somewhere else?  If in the userform , use `Me` in place of `CapitalCalls`

Comment: @TimWilliams it is in the module that opens the userform.

Comment: I think the issue is that PopulateFund is not operating on the same instance of `CapitalCalls` - I don't see where you create that or show it?  Is it already open?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm not sure i follow your question. The sub PopulateFund is in a module and the CapitalCalls Userform is within the same VBA Project. It is my understanding that one can simply fill the List/ComboBox with data from a procedure within a module so that when the userform initializes/opens the list is already there for the user to choose from.

Comment: Take a look at this https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/ and see if modify your approach using those guidelines helps

Comment: @TimWilliams My first sub i mentioned worked, and it, too, is calling on different userforms within the VBA Project. "DirectCalls" is a userform, ThirdParty is also a userform.  I don't understand why this sub can't populate the two different lists with the keys and items.

Answer (score 0):

Following from the link I posted above:

```vb
Sub UserFormStuff()

    'setup: "UserForm1" is a userform with 2 textboxes
    
    'this code relies on the "default instance"
    UserForm1.TextBox1 = "Test1"
    Test2
    UserForm1.Show '<< only textbox1 has content
    
    'this code uses an explicit instance of the userform
    Dim uf As UserForm1
    Set uf = New UserForm1
    uf.TextBox1 = "Test1 new"
    Test2_new uf   '<< pass our explicit instance to Test2_new
    uf.Show        '<< now both textboxes are populated
    
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    UserForm1.TextBox2 = "Test2" 'this just creates a *new* UserForm1
                                 '  which is not the same as the copy used
                                 '  in the sub which calls this 
End Sub

Sub Test2_new(uf As UserForm1)
    uf.TextBox2 = "Test2"    '<< use the provided instance
End Sub
```

Comment: but the userform ("CapitalCalls") contains 2 ComboBoxes (one is named "DCMFund" and the other combobox is named "FundDesc")  & it (meaning the userform) already exists. I'm not following your example nor the message you're trying to convey with the example.

Comment: When `Test2` is called it doesn't use the *same* `UserForm1` which is being used in `UserFormStuff` - it "auto-creates" a new instance of the userform and modifies that instance: when Test2 ends that new instance just gets destroyed and the instance in use in `UserFormStuff` is unaffected.

Comment: i think i follow now. you're suggesting that the default instance is what's screwed up, correct?

Comment: Yes, which is what the link I posted tries to cover - do not ever use the default instance: declare a variable for the userform and explicitly create an instance of the form for that variable.

Comment: so i added [Dim UF1 As UserForm] & Set UF1 = CapitalCalls, replaced all the "CapitalCalls" in the code with UF1 and still nothing -_-

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code where these forms actually get shown?  It's not clear when those instances actually get used, since you're working on multiple userforms here.

Comment: You can mail me a copy at the address in my comment

Comment: Hi Tim, i went ahead and sent it!

Comment: OK I will try to find some time later today.